# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#request.userPrincipal.name"

Tags: html

Whenever I am trying to run my web application I am getting the error below.
Can you please help.

```
2019-04-17 07:33:13.881 ERROR 21660 --- [io-9393-exec-10] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-9393-exec-10] Exception processing template "index": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#request.userPrincipal.name" (template: "/_header" - line 10, col 48)
    org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#request.userPrincipal.name" (template: "/_header" - line 10, col 48)

 Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
```

My header.html looks like this

```
<div class="header-bar">
     <th:block sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
          Hello
         <a th:href="@{/admin/accountInfo}" th:utext="${#request.userPrincipal.name}">..</a>
                &nbsp;|&nbsp;
          <a th:href="@{/admin/logout}">Logout</a>
      </th:block>

      <th:block sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
            <a th:href="@{/admin/login}">Login</a>
      </th:block>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try modify the code like this

```
<div class="header-container"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity">
```

And update the porn.xml

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>

    </dependency>
```

It will work correctly

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the code (isAuthenticated) is not taking effect.

Try updating your pom file to use the following version:
**thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5**

And update your html header file to:
**xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"**